# SQL Table design Issue. one table that contains two table Keys

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, linq

I have two tables :  Teacher and Lesson

Every teacher may have one or more lessons
i create a new table and  named  it TeacherLesson :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TeacherLesson] (
[Id]        INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[teacherID] INT NULL,
[LessonID]   INT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
```

);

when user try to add a new teacher he/she can choose lessons for new teacher
so i have a list of lessons that user can select them. that means i already have the lesson id but what about TeacherID
teacherID in teacher table is an identity specification (auto int) field so i don't know what is next id !
how i can insert new record in TeacherLesson Table with teacherID and LessonID
note that i use linq to SQL and WPF C#!

can i use foreign-key an make teacherID foreign-key and do something like this ?
 :

```
Teachers.TeacherLesson.add(newTeacherLesson);
```

is it technically OK ?

thank you!

Comment: You need to have/create a teacher first before you can add lessons

Comment: You need it the other way around; create the teacher and then, using that result, create the teacher-lesson-link.

Comment: thank you . i develop my app for an academy so Lessons  are now available teachers will change. for example CCNA may have several teachers. when user add a new teacher to academy teachers he/she want to identify that what lesson(s) teacher will teach to students !!!!

Comment: thank you MatBailie. can you explain how ? with Linq code maybe!!

Comment: Have you heard of Moodle?  It might be too much to try to help you this way.  If you insist, try an add form for the teacher and then use that to add the the teacher then, once they hit save, bring up the list of lessons for them to check off.